# Approximate the gradient of a sample point

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, vector-analysis, approximation, interpolation

Suppose we are given a set of sample points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I don't have any knowledge about the surface, but we may assume that it is smooth. I want to approximate the gradient of each sample point based on the smoothness of the surface (I can find the Taylor expansion around a small neighbourhood of the sample point) and the location of other sample points. Also, the sample data cannot be mapped to a regular grid. How should I go about doing this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is an interesting question. It touches the machine learning realm, in my opinion. There is a pletora of articles on the subject, each with its proposal. A first look makes it solvable, but further information like points closeness or assumptions of derivative boundedness are required to allow an approximation function design.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Thanks for the response! I am currently looking at Spline/ NURBS surface patches. I thought it might be a way to interpolate/ approximate the surface, not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: What is the difference betwen NURBS and Bézier surfaces?